# Properly configure python 2.7 after installation, preferably replacing existing python 2.6

Tags: python, pip

I am literally trying half a day to upgrade my python from 2.6 to 2.7 with no luck so far.
The linux distribution is:`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)`, and it came with `python 2.6`, which I want to now upgrade to `python 2.7`.
Here's the thing though; I already wrote huge amount of script lines in `python 2.6`, until I finally caved in to the need to use newer version of python. So I already have a lot of packages (`filelock`,`argparse`,`paramkio`,`psutil`,`dill` and more...), installed with `pip install PACKAGE` to my `python 2.6` script.

When I finally figured out how to install python 2.7 (I'll add the commands for reference):

```
$ wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz --no-check-certificate
$ tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
$ cd Python-2.7.6
$ ./configure
$ make 
$ sudo make altinstall
```

I ran into some more problems...

First of all, `python 2.7` was installed in `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` while `python 2.6` is at `/usr/bin/python2.6`. Naively, I thought that installing `python 2.7` will upgrade(=overwrite) the existing `python 2.6`. So when typing `python` from shell, the interpreter used is still `python 2.6`, instead of the newly installed `python 2.7`.

Second, running `pip install PACKAGE` still tries to install the package for `python 2.6`:

```
$ pip install filelock
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): filelock in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

btw, I noticed that `/usr/bin` has both `pip` and `easy_install` in it, unlike `/usr/local/bin/` (just in case this info can help solving this issue).

How do I solve these two issues?
I want `python 2.7` to be picked whenever you type `python` from shell, preferably taking `python 2.6`'s place in `/usr/bin/`, and
 I want `pip` to install packages for `python 2.7`.

I tried a lot of the suggested answers that seemed related, both here and in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `README` at the top of the source tree it describes many of the build choices you can make. In particular you can install the resulting files in `/usr` instead of the default `/usr/local` by doing

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

This will install, for example, `/usr/bin/python` as a symbolic link to `python2`, and that `python2` as a symbolic link to `python2.7`, the real binary.  You can easily check this before doing the final `sudo make install` by doing a non-root install into a simple subdir `x`:

```
make DESTDIR=x install
```

All the files will be installed under `x` and you can then browse to see that it corresponds to your needs. For example,

```
ls -l x/usr/bin/   
-rwxr-xr-x 1 meuh meuh      95 Sep 10 11:39 2to3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 meuh meuh      93 Sep 10 11:39 idle
-rwxr-xr-x 1 meuh meuh      78 Sep 10 11:39 pydoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 meuh meuh       7 Sep 10 11:39 python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 meuh meuh      14 Sep 10 11:39 python-config -> python2-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 meuh meuh       9 Sep 10 11:39 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 meuh meuh      16 Sep 10 11:39 python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 meuh meuh 7991432 Sep 10 11:39 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 meuh meuh    1668 Sep 10 11:39 python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 meuh meuh   18541 Sep 10 11:39 smtpd.py
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. 
What about `pip`? How can I install packages for `python 2.7`?

Comment: pip will just run the default python command, so if you have set `/usr/bin/python2` to `python2.7` it should work as you want. You can explicitly run `python2.6 -m pip install SomePackage` for example to force a particular version.